# Cannot resolve EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GBFLT)

Tags: c++, fopen, exc-bad-access, scanf, stdio

I'm very new at C++, maintaining my M.Sc on Information Systems. I have my first C++ homework announced and have been working on it for a couple of days. The aim of the code is simply to read info from a text file and print it on screen, then make calculation on some of it and print results to a new text file. However when I build, it gives the error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GBFLT)

in the first fscanf in readInfo function.

I know the code I wrote is not completely efficient but I just want it to print on screen and on output file correctly. I would really appreciate if anyone help me to resolve this error. I am about to freak out...

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char id[10];
    char name[40];
    float midterm;
    float final;
    int attendance;
}Student;


void readInfo(Student studentList[], int *count)
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("scores.txt","r");

    char surname = '\0';
    *count=0;
    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        fscanf(fin,"%c %c %c %f %f %d",studentList[*count].id, studentList[*count].name, &surname, &studentList[*count].midterm, &studentList[*count].final, &studentList[*count].attendance);

        strcpy(studentList[*count].name, studentList[*count].name);
        strcat(studentList[*count].name, " ");
        strcat(studentList[*count].name, &surname);

        *count++;
    }fclose(fin);

    printf("%-7s%17s %5.1f %5.1f %-2d\n", studentList[*count].id, studentList[*count].name, studentList[*count].midterm, studentList[*count].final, studentList[*count].attendance);
}

float studentScore(float midterm, float final, int attendance)
{
    float score;
    int maxAttend=0;
    char id[10];
    char name[40];
    char surname[40];

    FILE *fin=fopen("scores.txt","r");

    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        fscanf(fin,"%c %c %c %f %f %d",id, name, surname, &midterm, &final, &attendance);

        if(attendance>maxAttend)
            maxAttend=attendance;

    }fclose(fin);

    score=midterm*0.3+final*0.5+(maxAttend/20)*attendance;

    return score;

}

float avgScore(Student studentList[])
{
    float average;

    int count;

    int totalScore=0;

    readInfo(studentList, &count);

    for(int i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        totalScore+=studentScore(studentList[count].midterm, studentList[count].final, studentList[count].attendance);
    }

    average=totalScore/count;

    return average;
}

void courseGradeOutput(Student studentList[])
{
    FILE *fout=fopen("output.txt","w");

    int count;
    int pass=0;
    float score;
    char letterGrade[2];
    float avg;

    fprintf(fout,"\tId\tName, Surname = (Score, Letter)\n");

    readInfo(studentList, &count);

    for(int i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        score=studentScore(studentList[i].midterm, studentList[i].final, studentList[i].attendance);

        if(score>=0 && score<=49)
        {    letterGrade[0]={'F'};
            letterGrade[1]={'F'};}
        else if (score>=50 && score<=59)
        {letterGrade[0]={'F'};
            letterGrade[1]={'D'};}
        else if (score>=60 && score<=64)
        {letterGrade[0]={'D'};
            letterGrade[1]={'D'};}
        else if (score>=65 && score<=69)
        {letterGrade[0]={'D'};
            letterGrade[1]={'C'};}
        else if (score>=70 && score<=74)
        {letterGrade[0]={'C'};
            letterGrade[1]={'C'};}
        else if (score>=75 && score<=79)
        {letterGrade[0]={'C'};
            letterGrade[1]={'B'};}
        else if (score>=80 && score<=84)
        {letterGrade[0]={'B'};
            letterGrade[1]={'B'};}
        else if (score>=85 && score<=89)
        {letterGrade[0]={'B'};
            letterGrade[1]={'A'};}
        else if (score>=90 && score<=100)
        {letterGrade[0]={'A'};
            letterGrade[1]={'A'};}

        if(score>=60)
            pass++;

        fprintf(fout,"%7s %16s = ( %4.1f, %6s\n)", studentList[i].id, studentList[i].name, score, letterGrade);

    }

    avg=avgScore(studentList);

    fprintf(fout,"\nSome statistics:\n\nClass Avg Score: %5.2f \n #Students: %11d \n #Passed Students: %4d \n #Failed Students: %4d",avg,count,pass,(count-pass));

    fclose(fout);

}

int main()
{   Student studentList[100];
    int count;

    readInfo(studentList, &count);

    courseGradeOutput(studentList);
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTq6i.png)

Comment: Are you sure fscanf crashes? Side notes: `strcpy(studentList[*count].name, studentList[*count].name);` is nonsense. surname is a char, you only read a char but you `strcat(..., &surname)`. strcat-ing a char won't work.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is fscanf, since the error is shown on that line (Screenshot). I don't know if showing the error on that line means something else.
I am trying to put both name and surname info from txt file into studentList[i].name.  Besides my code is nonsense, I would appreciate if you can guide me to make it right...

Comment: `*count++` does not do what you think it does. It first increments the pointer `count` and then dereferences it. This is probably what causes the crash. You need to write `(*count)++`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Error solved. Now there is the issue that code prints nothing near what I want it to print.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is most likely caused by either `fscanf` followed by `strcpy` and/or by your increment of `count` inside `readInfo`.

You write `*count++`, but this is equivalent to

```
count = count + 1;
*(count-1);
```

What you want is `(*count)++`.

The `fscanf` scans characters `%c` where you want to scan strings `%s` (for `id` and `name`). You also want to scan `surname` as a string, probably, but then you need to change `surname` to be a character array:

```
char surname[30];
*count=0;
while(!feof(fin))
{
    fscanf(fin,"%s %s %s %f %f %d",studentList[*count].id, studentList[*count].name, surname, &studentList[*count].midterm, &studentList[*count].final, &studentList[*count].attendance);

    strcat(studentList[*count].name, " ");
    strcat(studentList[*count].name, surname);

    (*count)++;
}
fclose(fin);
```

I also removed the first `strcpy` as you were copying from a buffer to itself, which is not allowed.

I haven't checked the other functions thoroughly, but I do notice that you do not use the result from your `readInfo` called from `main` when you do `courseGradeOutput`: this function calls `readInfo` again. You could modify it to take the read student records and the count, so you don't have to read the file again.

You might also want to improve `scanf` a bit to pass a width, such as `%29s` for `name`, to avoid overflowing the buffer when the `name` inside the file is too long; and the same for the other strings you scan. You should then also look at the return value of `fscanf` and only use the things you scanned when it succeeded in scanning every argument.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem, using the gray/green checkmark next to the answer.